# Object variable not set - Why is this Dictionary object not being returned?

Tags: vba, dictionary, object

In my code I am using three functions..

Function `CreateDict()` - creates a dictionary object and returns it

Function `UpdateDict(arg)` - populates the supplied dictionary with new values

Function `RefreshDict()` - used to store current state of dictionary temporarily, before clearing, meanwhile creating a new dictionary where the new state is stored, after which it is fed back into the current dictionary.

The problem resides in `RefreshDict()` and the code looks like so:

```
Set nd = CreateDict()
Set td = cd 'storing current dictionary state into temp dictionary
cd = UpdateDict(nd) 'update state of current dictionary
td.RemoveAll 'Clear the content; free memory
```

Note: `cd` is declared globally at the begining of the program: `Set cd = CreateDict()`

Compiler fails at `cd = UpdateDict(nd)` but why is the dictionary object not returned from `UpdateDict`?

Comment: Can you provide the code of `UpdateDict`? Is it really a `Function`?

Comment: `Set td = cd` does not copy the dictionary it copies the reference so `td.RemoveAll` is the same as `cd.RemoveAll`